# Spring boot getting the value from the repository and use that value in another method as return type

Tags: jpa, spring-boot

I am working on Spring Boot Where i am facing issue while fetching values from a particular column and use it as return value in another class. I had followed the steps as

1) fetching the value using repository in service class as below

```
public MyEntity fetchDate(){

   return MyRepository.findByName(date)   
}
```

2) How can I write a method in controller class which returns `fromDate` value which I passed in `findByName()` method as

```
public Date getDate(Long Id){
     myService.fetchDate();
   return date; 
}
```

Comment: i'm unable to get date value as fetchDate() returns entity class

Answer (score 0, accepted):

MyEntity.getFromDate () can return the required value.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you should be able to override the query behavior with the `@Query` annotation on your interface as follows and it should provide the functionality you're interested in:

```
public interface MyEntityRepository extends JpaRepository<MyEntity, Long> {
  @Query("SELECT e.myDateField FROM MyEntity e WHERE e.name = :name")
  Date findByName(String name)
}
```